# Delete a Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

How do I delete a group in Facebook?

I am the owner of a Facebook group and there are no other users except me (I removed them all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Facebook Help Center](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=18792) says:

> Our system automatically deletes
>   groups once they're empty (no
>   members). If you created the group,
>   you can delete the group by removing
>   all members and then yourself. Note
>   that if you were not the first admin
>   and creator of this group, you will
>   not be able to delete the group unless
>   the group creator has left it
>   voluntarily.